# First success, second same request error stub response

Tags: wiremock

Here my wiremock stub mapping:

```
{
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "urlPattern": "/api/myApp"
  },
  "response": {
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "status": 200
  }
}
```

So when client execute http request with url pattern = **/api/myApp** then WireMock return success http status = 200.

Nice. It's work fine.

But I need when client execute second request with same url pattern the WireMock must return this stub response:

```
   {
      "request": {
        "method": "POST",
        "urlPattern": "/api/myApp"
      },
      "response": {
        "headers": {
          "Content-Type": "application/json"
        },
        "status": 401
      }
    }
```

So:

First request -> stub response 200

Second same request  -> stub response 401

Is it possible by WireMock ?

Answer (score 3):

If you are always going to have the pattern of the first call is successful and the second call is unsuccessful, you can use Scenarios to achieve this.

```json
{
    "scenarioName": "My Scenario",
    "requiredScenarioState": "Started",
    "newScenarioState": "Triggered Once",
    "request": {}
    "response": {
        "status": 200
    }
}
```

```json
{
    "scenarioName": "My Scenario",
    "requiredScenarioState": "Triggered Once",
    "newScenarioState": "Started",
    "request": {}
    "response": {
        "status": 401
    }
}
```

`scenarioName` is any string that you want to name the scenario
`requiredScenarioState` is the state the scenario has to be in. All Scenarios begin at a state of "Started".
`newScenarioState` is any string to denote the new Scenario State.

In the above, it will always alternate between successful 200 calls and unsuccessful 401 calls.

For more information on [Stateful Behavior in WireMock, check out the docs](http://wiremock.org/docs/stateful-behaviour/)

Comment: Not work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66446972/scenario-first-response-ok-but-second-same-request-return-404-error-code