# Scenario: First response success, but second same request return 404 error code

Tags: wiremock

I need when do first request then get stub response code = 401.

When do second SAME request then get stub response code = 200.

To do this I use scenario.

Here my WireMock mapping in ONE file:

```
{
  "scenarioName": "Request transfer, 401",
  "requiredScenarioState": "Started",
  "newScenarioState": "Triggered Once",
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "urlPattern": "/api/T2A"
  },
  "response": {
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "status": 401
  }
}

{
  "scenarioName": "Request transfer, 200",
  "requiredScenarioState": "Triggered Once",
  "newScenarioState": "Started",
  "request": {
    "method": "POST",
    "urlPattern": "/api/T2A"
  },
  "response": {
    "headers": {
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    },
    "status": 200,
    "bodyFileName": "VB/back/request_transfer.json"
  }
}
```

When do first request I get stub response = 401.

Nice. But when do second same request WireMock return error code = 404.

```
                                               Request was not matched
                                               =======================

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Closest stub                                             | Request                                                  |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                                           |
POST                                                       | POST
/api/T2A                                                   | /api/T2A
                                                           |
                                                           |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

2021-03-02 22:44:34.802 Request received:
127.0.0.1 - POST /api/T2A

{"MTS":"2be192ca-dabe-47b9-b","IDNP":"1"}


Matched response definition:
(no response definition configured)

Response:
HTTP/1.1 404
(no headers)


2021-03-02 22:44:34.805 Received request to /not-matched with body
```

Why second SAME request not return stub response status = 200?

Answer (score 1):

Your scenarios have to have the same name. This is how WireMock identifies that the mapping belongs to that scenario.

You are getting a 404 because there is no mapping for the Scenario `Request transfer, 401` and in the ScenarioState `Triggered Once`.

Changing the scenario names to `Request transfer` for both mappings would resolve your issue.